# Excel VBA - Performing function to each cells in range

Tags: excel, range, vba

Let's say I have a range called rng1

```
Set rng1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1","A5")
```

Is there a quick and easy way to perform a mathematical function, lets say divide all those cell values by 2, for all the cells in rng1?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Try: `With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B5")
        .Formula = "=A1/2"
        .Value = .Value
    End With`

Comment: or use the paste-special divide on your range either manually or with VBA

Answer (score 14):

It's very easy, but the final code will depend on where you want to store the new values. For example, if you want to store the values divided by 2 in the next column:

```vb
Sub test()

Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Range("A1:A5")
    cell.Offset(, 1).Value = cell.Value / 2
Next

End Sub
```

Mind you there are more efficient ways to do this than using offset if your range is large, but for a smaller range, this is totally acceptable and fast.

If you want to overwrite the values, you can simply use `cell.Value` in place of `cell.Offset(,1).Value`

Answer (score 2):

Another Way

```
Sub Main()
    [B1:B5] = [INDEX((A1:A5/2),)]
End Sub
```

How it works is well explained [here.](http://usefulgyaan.wordpress.com/2013/06/12/vba-trick-of-the-week-slicing-an-array-without-loop-application-index/)